# How to make systemd message not show in /var/log/message

Tags: centos7, systemd

Custom applications in the systemd how to customize the log path, the default to / var/log/message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problems by using

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/apppath/appname > /filepath/filename 2>&1'
```

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html

Comment: ```
[Unit]
Description=app 
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/apppath
ExecStart=/apppath/appname
StandardOutput=syslog
SyslogFacility=local6
StandardError=syslog
Restart=always
RestartSec=20

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
local6.info    /var/log/app.log
```